# How to include a jsp page in velocity template?

Tags: java, jsp, velocity

In my project i  have my header and footer in jsp and i  want to add  these header and footer to an existing project in which, the header and footer are in velocity template(.vm)

please help me...
thanks in advance...

Comment: If yo have heade and footer in jsp it would be more naturally include result of calling velociy template into jsp page, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Two paths toward this that i see, both require VelocityTools.

Either use the ImportTool to import the two jsp pages.

Or create a little jsp file that includes the header and footer and uses the VelocityViewTag to #parse('your_template.vm')