# Including jsp file in velocity template

Tags: java, velocity

Is there a way to include (and parse) JSPs in Velocity templates?

I am migrating an application from using JSPs to Velocity templates and I still want to be able to use some of the JSP includes I have.

I tried the #include directive and $import but both are not working. i am getting Velocity  [debug] Null reference error..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663388/how-to-include-a-jsp-page-in-velocity-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible jsp and velocity templates can't be used together.